# Necklace infinte sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, necklace-and-bracelets

Consider the function:
$$S(n)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{j^n}{2^j}=\frac1 2+\frac{2^n}{4}+\frac{3^n}{8}+\frac{4^n}{16}+\frac{5^n}{32}+...$$

Euler found the sum of the first few of these as:

$S(0)=1$; (as per the usual geometric series.)

$S(1)=2$; etc.  This creates a series of sums as follows:

1, 2, 6, 26, 150, 1082, 9366, 94586, … , which is the OEIS sequence A000629, “Number of necklaces of partitions of $n+1$ labelled beads”.

My question is - what connection is there between this infinite series and necklace combinatorics?  Or is the connection accidental or illusory?

Comment: Both are given by $\operatorname{Li}_{-n}(1/2)$. One way to view the connection is that we have $\operatorname{Li}_{-n}(1/2) = 2^{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left \langle  \!{n\atop  k}\!\right \rangle2^{k-n}$ and the Eulerian Numbers come up when studying increasing sequences in a partition (which is obviously related the necklace problem)

Comment: By "Li", do you mean logarithmic integral?  If not, what function?

Comment: I am referring to the nth polylogarithm.